# How to access Input and Output audio stream of a Voice call as well as VoIP call on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, voice-recording

I am trying to access the Input and Output audio stream of any Voice call as well as VoIP calls. The functionality should be very similar to the native call recorder already available.

I have already looked into [MediaRecorder.AudioSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) but **Voice_uplink, Voice_downlink**, and **VOICE_COMMUNICATION** are not allowed for Third-Party apps.

My use-case is, I am trying to build an application that needs access to the call audio, be it voice call or VoIP, etc. My app will do post-processing on the recorded audio, once the call gets over.

Any help would be highly appreciated.